# How to derive FRP from Directed Acyclic Graphs?

Tags: haskell, directed-acyclic-graphs, frp

I am currently researching for my next project. This is in a pre-planning phase so this question is just to get an overview on existing technology.

#### Setup

I have a directed acyclic graph (DAG) with multiple inputs and output, think artificial neuronal network for now:

[image: Directed acyclic graph]

The common way to process such a structure is to process the whole network on every (time-)step. I believe that is the method used by frp libraries such as [`netwire`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/netwire).

Now I am in the fortunate position that I have a stream of events that each presents the change in *one* of the input nodes. The idea is that I probably don't have to step each node in the network if I can statically know that a given change will only affect a part of it.

**Example**

In the image above 5, 7 and 3 are inputs, 11 and 8 are 'hidden' and 2, 9 and 10 are output nodes. A change at node 5 will only affect node 11 and in effect nodes 2, 9 and 10. I won't need to process nodes 7, 3 and 8.

#### The goal

Process this kind of network with as little latency as possible. The size of the graphs will probably reach up to 100k nodes, with a moderate amount of calculation being done per node.

#### The plan

I hope that someone will step up and advertise library X that just gets the job done.

Otherwise my current plan is to derive a calculation per input node from the graph description. Probably I will use the `Par` monad so that I won't have to deal with data dependencies myself and still get to benefit from multicore machines.

#### The questions

- Is there any library out there that just does what I need?
- Is my `Par` plan feasible? How much does this depend on the amount of processing needed in each node?

Comment: I'm not sure about the Par side of things, but I actually asked a similar question a few hours before you. Instead of nodes on the graph connecting directly to each other they reference an Id number of the target node and look it up. To get performance boost I opted for a lookup using an array: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25799663/3792504 - you could also try looking at FGL http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fgl (based on http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/fgl/)

Comment: Nice ... I'll have a look into your question.

Comment: Have you looked into the Actor model of concurrency? It seems like you could do something Erlang style and spin up a bunch of actors (one per neuron) which could message one another with updates. I'm not sure how well this would work for low-latency with the number of nodes you want though.

Comment: @paul I thought about that too, but dismissed it for two reasons: a) per-neuron workload is probably to little to overcome the whole actor overhead. b) it gets harder to control the effects of the net. With parallel processing it is "change input, wait, collect outputs", with concurrent processing more like: "change input, wait, oh there is one change on the output ... and another ..."

Comment: @Florian yeah, `b` had crossed my mind; in order to sync them you'd probably have to have some sort of ID and/or have each neuron know how many inputs it should wait for. (Probably more overhead than it's worth.)

Comment: @Florian You might look into _Arrowized_ FRP -- check out the paper "Genuinely Functional User Interfaces" for examples. The `proc` method does some magic w.r.t. updating.

Comment: Thanks @paul I'll have a look at the paper.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problems like this are usually encoded against either an `Applicative` or `Arrow` abstraction. I'll only discuss `Applicative`. The `Applicative` type class, found in `Control.Applicative`, allows values and functions to be provided via `pure` and functions to be applied to values with `<*>`.

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    -- | Lift a value.
    pure :: a -> f a

    -- | Sequential application.
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Your example graph could be very simply encoded for an `Applicative` (replacing each node with addition) as

```
example1 :: (Applicative f, Num a) => f a -> f a -> f a -> f (a, a, a)
example1 five seven three = 
    let
        eleven = pure (+) <*> five   <*> seven
        eight  = pure (+) <*> seven  <*> three
        two    = pure id  <*> eleven
        nine   = pure (+) <*> eleven <*> eight
        ten    = pure (+) <*> eleven <*> three
    in
        pure (,,) <*> two <*> nine <*> ten
```

The same encoding can be created programmatically from the representation of a graph by traversing the graph such that each node will be visited after all of its dependencies.

There are three optimizations you may desire that can't be implemented for a network encoded using only `Applicative`. The general strategy is to encode the problem in terms of `Applicative` and a few additional classes as needed for optimization or extra features. You then provide one or more interpreters that implement the necessary classes. This lets you separate the problem from the implementation, allowing you to write your own interpreter or use an existing library like [reactive](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive), [reactive-banana](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/reactive-banana), or [mvc-updates](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/06/spreadsheet-like-programming-in-haskell.html). I am not going to discuss how to write these interpreters or adapt the representation given here to a specific interpreter. I'm only going to discuss the common representation of the program that's needed in order for the underlying interpreter to be able to exploit these optimizations. All three of the libraries I linked can avoid recomputing values and can accommodate the following optimizations.

#### Observable Sharing

In the previous example, the intermediate node `eleven` is only defined once, but is used in three different places. An implementation of `Applicative` won't be able to see through the referential transparency to see that these three `eleven`s are all the same. You can either assume that the implementation uses some [IO magic to peek through referential transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25698375/414413) or define the network so that an implementation can see that a computation is being reused.

The following is the class of `Applicative` `Functor`s where the result of a computation can be divided and reused in multiple computations. This class isn't defined in a library anywhere that I know of.

```
class Applicative f => Divisible f where
    (</>) :: f a -> (f a -> f b) -> f b

infixl 2 </>
```

Your example can then be very simply encoded for a `Divisible` `Functor` as

```
example2 :: (Divisible f, Num a) => f a -> f a -> f a -> f (a, a, a)
example2 five seven three = 
    pure (+) <*> five   <*> seven </> \eleven ->
    pure (+) <*> seven  <*> three </> \eight  ->
    pure id  <*> eleven           </> \two    ->
    pure (+) <*> eleven <*> eight </> \nine   ->
    pure (+) <*> eleven <*> three </> \ten    ->
    pure (,,) <*> two <*> nine <*> ten
```

#### Sums and Abelian Groups

A typical neuron computes a weighted sum of its inputs and applies a response function to that sum. For a neuron with a large in degree, summing all of its inputs is time consuming. An easy optimization for updating a sum is to subtract the old value and add the new value. This exploits three properties of addition:

**Inverse** - `a * b * b⁻¹ = a` Subtraction is the inverse of adding a number, this inverse allows us to remove the previously added number from the total

**Commutativity** - `a * b = b * a` Addition and subtraction reach the same result regardless of the order they are performed in. This lets us reach the same result when we subtract the old value and add the new value to the total even if the old value wasn't the most recently added value.

**Associativity** - `a * (b * c) = (a * b) * c` Addition and subtraction can be performed in arbitrary groupings and still reach the same result. This lets us reach the same result when we subtract the old value and add the new value to the total even it the old value was added somewhere in the middle of the additions.

Any structure with these properties as well as closure and an identity is an [Abelian group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group). The following dictionary holds enough information for an underlying library to perform the same optimization

```
data Abelian a = Abelian {
    id  :: a,
    inv :: a -> a,
    op  :: a -> a -> a
}
```

This is the class of structures that can total Abelian groups

```
class Total f where 
    total :: Abelian a -> [f a] -> f a
```

Similar optimization is possible for the construction of maps.

#### Thresholding and Equality

Another typical operation in neural networks is to compare a value to a threshold and determine the response entirely based on whether or not the value passed the threshold. If an update to an input doesn't change which side of the threshold the value falls on, the response doesn't change. If the response doesn't change, there's no reason to recalculate all of the downstream nodes. The ability to either detect that there was no change to the threshold `Bool` or the response is equality. The following is the class of structures that can exploit equality. `stabilize` provides the `Eq` instance to the underlying structure.

```
class Stabilizes f where
    stabilize :: Eq a => f a -> f a
```

Comment: Wow ... what an answer. I guess this answers more than I asked for. Just one little question: Is there a reason you use `pure f <*>` instead of just `f <$>` in your examples?

Comment: `pure f <*>` and `f <$>` are exactly equivalent. `f <$>` is infix `fmap`. According to Control.Applicative "As a consequence of these laws, the `Functor` instance for `f` will satisfy `fmap f x = pure f <*> x`". http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html Therefore `f <$> x = pure f <*> x`. Both `<*>` and `<$>` have fixity `infixl 4`.

Comment: Thanks, I was just wondering why someone would choose the first over the later.

Comment: Also, `example2` uses [Continuation Passing Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) which can be written using the [Continuation Monad](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2008/12/mother-of-all-monads.html)